# HTML5 Input Type Email

Tags: php, html

I'm thinking of using the `input type="email"` to me new site but I have question if would you prefer to use input type text then Check the value by regular expression or use this HTML 5 Email

```
E-mail: <input type="email" name="usremail" />
```

Does the HTML input type Email have issue when used(browser or usage)?

Comment: I don't think you need to include a php tag for this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use html5 email to validate but it only checks for XXXX@XXXX so that's a valid email lol

for me at least I would say just use [jquery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and always to server side validation

it won't hurt to use the email type as browsers that don't support it will convert to text type

you may want to look at [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) for backward compatiblility

Comment: that jquery validate is a plugin??

Comment: yes for jquery very widely used and well documented made by one of the guys that works at jquery

Comment: if thats the case xxxx@xxxx is a valid email. it would be easy to check using shorter regex with email input type. ill just check the ending part .com,.net.org??

Comment: 'xxxx@xxxx is a valid email." is for the html5 validation. jquery validate is much better

Comment: I just got a link http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60701/input-type-email-allows-testtest-why and this is what I know something that i didn't know.

Answer (score 5):

The browser won't do any validation if it doesn't support it.  You can use [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect whether or not it does, and act accordingly.  (Like use native HTML5 validation, or instead use something like [jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) )

According to http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.email.html, the input email uses this regex to verify it is an email:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
```

You should be validating these things server side as well anyway.

Comment: +1 for the w3-pattern. Good to have some reference, when arguing over the right approach for validation.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 - as you know - is not fully supported by the available browsers , this `input type='email'` is supported by Chrome , FF , but not supported by IE old versions .. There's a work around solution : you can stay using these HTML5 inputs , and use this JS library to support the other broswers : http://code.google.com/p/webforms2/

Comment: i see.. i was thinking of using it because its was smaller code to use and will lessen the coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you have support bowser then it won't have any issue. If they are not supported it works like regular text fields.
[http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_input_types.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp)

Comment: so all browser support this input type??

Comment: IE and Safari doesn't support however following code might help to make support for IE9.
`<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->`

Answer (score 0):

You can use
Email:

```
enter <input type="text" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" >
```

for HTML5(http://davidwalsh.name/html5-email)
here

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers. At least have the courtesy to explain why and how the content of this link will help the OP. If the website you link to goes down, your question will be downvoted and probably removed.

Answer (score -1):

this input type "E-mail: " does not work in IE9 and safari so it will be treated as a  it only works on google chrome and mozila fire fox, this E-mail:  automatically validates if the browser supports HTML5